# How to show difference between views page and views block

Tags: views, blocks, 7

I have created a view page, to this same page I will add a block by clicking on add button. So whatever changes I will do in the block is affecting the view page also. So how can I configure this, so that my block changes should apply only to block and not to page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **This page override**  option in view field configuration instead of **All display** 
[image]

Comment: Thank you Vamsi.. Is this work for adding an attachment to that same view instead of block?

Comment: I think it will work. @Suraj